# Converting child class object to base class object

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a child class `B` which is inheriting from base class `A`.

My base class has a function `void DoSomething()` which modifies the *base class* object.

If I call the function from child class object is there any way by which I can ensure the modified object will be of base class type.

For ex.

```
class BaseClass
{
    int prop1;
    int prop2;

     void DoSomething()
    {
        prop1=prop1*5;
    }

}

class ChildClass:BaseClass
{
    int prop3;
    
}

class Program
{
ChildClass c= new ChildClass();
c.DoSomething();
}
```

now suppose childclass can only have prop1 value up to 10. if the value is more than 50 then its still of type BaseClass but not ChildClass. So is there a way by which I can ensure after calling c.DoSomething() the object will be considered of type BaeeClass not of type childclass to the compiler.

Comment: You don´t need to ensure that, as every `B` already **is** an `A`. You can allways cast a derived-class object to its base-class. `(A)myInstanceOfB`. But that cast is redundant, though.

Comment: You lost me at "*If I call the function from child class object is there any way by which I can ensure the modified object will be of base class type.*" What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Could you show an example of code that does the wrong thing because of this problem, and explain what you want it do to instead?

Comment: After modification the object may no be of type B anymore... dat is why I need to ensure its of type A not B

Comment: @TheGeneral   I have tried to create a dummy code to explain to the problem further

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I have tried to create a dummy code to explain to the problem further

Comment: That doesn't make sense, no matter what you do with the members or data it doesn't stop child being the parent since it inherits. The question is more why do you want to do this as it seems like this may not be the correct pattern to use here

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of **Access Modifiers** to achieve your requirement. You can use protected.

Below is the code snippet:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Child objChild = new Child();
            objChild.ModififyParent();          /// Works fine
            Parent objParent = new Parent();
            objParent.DoSomething();            /// Doesn't work due to its protection level
        }
    }
    public class Parent
    {
        private string MyName;
        protected void DoSomething() 
        {
            MyName = MyName + "modified";
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public void ModififyParent() {
            base.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion, `protected` will help here? OP does not mention anything about a member not being accessable. Seems like a really wild guess.

Comment: I have added a dummy code to further explain my question. thanx

Comment: I didn't get exactly. What I understand is: Base class properties will be updated only by Base class and Child class should not update the Base class's properties. 
Child class can access the Base class properties but should not modify.

Is my understanding correct?